# C# Directory.GetFiles adds extra file extension to returned path

Tags: c#, file

At the moment I'm currently trying to get all files from a specified directory. The files I'm looking for end with the file type .ship, however, my code returns "path\NameOfFiles.ship.ship" and I can't for the life of me decide where the extra file extension is added.

Here's the function I use

```
public static List<SaveEntry> GetAllSavesFromProfile(string ProfileName)
{
    if (IsProfileMissing(ProfileName))
    {
        Debug.LogError("Couldn't find save from profile. Check if it exists before calling this function");
        return new List<SaveEntry>();
    }

    List<SaveEntry> ListToReturn = new List<SaveEntry>();

    List<string> SaveEntries = Directory.GetFiles(Application.persistentDataPath + "/Profile_" + ProfileName, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Where(s => s.EndsWith(".ship", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).ToList<string>();

    foreach (string entry in SaveEntries)
    {
        ListToReturn.Add(LoadShip(ProfileName, entry));
    }

    return ListToReturn;
}
```

I'm pretty I'm doing something wrong with the Where function, but I can't decide exactly where.

Comment: I don't think the problem lies with the `Where` extension method. Where abouts do you observe this erroneous file name? Would you please put a breakpoint beneath the `SaveEntries` variable and inspect the file names there?

Comment: What does `LoadShip` do? It seems more likely for that to be the problem than what you've shown so far.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "Where do you observe this file name"? I'm not quite sure I understand.

Comment: @TiesonT. Oh god, I feel so stupid now. You're right, it's added in the LoadShip function. Thanks :)

Comment: @DanielEverland You know that the file names contain `.ship.ship`. How do you know this?

Comment: @DanielEverland Good to see that you solved the problem :)

Comment: @ByteBlast Thanks!

I'm in Unity so it gives me an error that states what it's looking for. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect your filenames contains an extra `.ship`. You can verify that [if you change your settings](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/865219/en-us) to show file extensions.

Also, you can use a search pattern instead of using `Where`

```
Directory.GetFiles(Application.persistentDataPath + "/Profile_" + ProfileName, "*.ship", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
```

Comment: Turns out that as @TiestonT. pointed out, I foolishly add it in the LoadShip function, although I do like your way of getting the ship file type. Cheers, I'll add it :)